# Did anyone manage to get the DVDRental example using Direct to SwiftUI running?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, database-connection, swiftui

I've loaded the finished DVDRental demo app 
with

```
        git clone -b branches/10-customized \
           https://github.com/DirectToSwift/DVDRental.git
```

as well as tried it with

```
       git clone -b branches/01-default-rulemodel \
          https://github.com/DirectToSwift/DVDRental.git
```

(see http://www.alwaysrightinstitute.com/directtoswiftui/) and restored the demo database. 
Currently, I am trying to execute the app, following the instructions on http://www.alwaysrightinstitute.com/directtoswiftui/ and ReadMe from https://github.com/DirectToSwift/DVDRental. Which means I have named the database accordingly and built the app.  In fact, you should only install the database, download the project and it should be running without any change. However, the app remains on the launch screen, showing a "connecting database" message.

Through an exhaustive debugging process, I came to the conclusion that there is something wrong with the authentication. However, I could not determine what exactly goes wrong.

Is there anybody who tried it and it worked?

Using:

Xcode 11.3.1; Swift 5; iOS 13; Postgres.app Version 2.3.3e; PostgreSQL 12

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Update:  there is no problem with the database. I can connect via psql, clients such as postico or navicat, or with my own apps using PostgresClientKit. The problem has been tracked down to the authentication process. Therefore I'm pretty sure that the problem lies somewhere there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the developers "forgot" to enable authentication.

> Right, it is quite possible that I didn't have auth on. I'll see
>   whether I can give it a try on the weekend.

needless to say, two months later it is still not fixed